# Multiple field names on single input

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm new to React and Formik. I have a problem on how to get both the lat and lang in location object. I get [object, Object ] on my input location. To demonstrate my problem. I created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-payne-hk6nd. Thank you!

Comment: [object, Object] means you are trying to show entire object, and not the actual values of properties in that object (js does not know how to print entire object with keys and values by itself). Your object has lat, lang properties in it, so instead of location object, try showing location.lat and location.lang

Comment: Yes that was I was thinking. I couldn't just wrap my head on how to return it on a single value. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your sandbox with the fix

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-goodall-6ph1j)

Basically, I changed your `mapPropsToValues` to this:

```
  mapPropsToValues({ location }) {
    const lat = location.lat || "";
    const lng = location.lng || "";
    return {
      location: `${lat}, ${lng}`,
    };
  },
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I feel so dumb right now hehe.

Comment: Hi would it be possible to store the updated lat and lng within the location: {lat, lng} instead of location?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your MyEnhancedForm to this:

```
mapPropsToValues({ location }) {

return {location:[location.lat,location.lng]}
```

}

or something along those lines. this way you can render both lng and lat

Comment: You are welcome :). You can also add check like you used location.lat || "" if needed.

Comment: Hi would it be possible to store the updated lat and lng within the location: {lat, lng} instead of location?

Answer (score 0):

In `MyForm`, you will get `values` props.

```
const { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting } = props;

let location = values.location;
location = `lat:${location.lat}, lng:${location.lng}`
```

In `Field` you need to set `value` prop,

```
<Field value={location} name="location" type="text" className="c-input" readOnly />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t6eceo)

Comment: Thank you but I also needed to change the value of the input while ondrag. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyForm = props => {
  const { touched, errors, isSubmitting, values } = props; // Formik pass values to props

  return (
    <Form>
      <input type="text" value={`${values.location.lat}, ${values.location.lng}`} readOnly/> // We preferred input instead of Field.
      {touched.location && errors.location && (
        <p className="u-text-red-600 text-xs mt-2 absolute u-mt-4">
          {errors.location}
        </p>
      )}
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="c-button c-button--info c-button--block u-my-4"
        disabled={isSubmitting}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
      <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
    </Form>
  );
};
```